# Dev server test for app engine when communicating with other server

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine Standard to write a small application, let's call it AppX.
AppX is supposed to receive a POST message from another website, let's say B, and then do some processing and show on its mainpage.

The question is:
I don't know how to use dev_app server to debug. As if I use dev_app server, the server will run locally without https, then I don't know how to send a POST message from website B.

Comment: What is website B? Is there a reason you can't have that running locally as well on a different port to test sandbox to sandbox?

Comment: You can just send send POST data to your dev appserver using a tool like curl, or using a python library like requests.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes I was doing that. But just wondering any chance I can test with website B as well..

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud shell is a very limited shell too, which does have [limited ports](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) enabled for outgoing connections only.

Although there might be a way to configure it, I think the easiest way to test calls from website B to a dev_app would be configuring a GCE virtual machine with a fixed IP. There you can configure the firewall freely, and also not worry any non-interactive session to finish abruptly.